# I have alraedy imported 'numpy' but still getting this error

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook

```
import numpy as np
np.zeros(10)
```

---

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 1
----> 1 np.zeros(10)

NameError: name 'np' is not defined
```

I'm trying to get arrays of zeroes
should be expecting this

`array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])`

Comment: execute your cell with the "import numpy as np" again!

Answer (score -1):

Ensure that you have:

```
import numpy as np
```

at the top of your script.

I suspect that you wrote `import numpy` at the top of your script - which will not allow you to access `numpy` using the `np` shorthand. However, `numpy.zeros(10)` would work following this format.

Comment: ah yes, i was doing exercises and just realized i have to write code by importing numpy in every cell.
thanks!